# Moving a Drupal between linux servers, best practice to avoid file-ownership problems

Tags: permissions, apache-2.2, linux

I want to port over a Drupal commons 6.24 site from a local LAMP stack to a production server. Both systems runs on OpenSuse Linux.

How can I achieve this? What are the most important steps? How should I handle file-ownership?

It's important for me to have to have full control on the file ownership. If I use the wwwrun account, I frequently run into problems, due to a very strict server admin.

See for example the long history of looking for fixes and solutions 
in [this thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19628/drupal-commons-site-has-no-style-after-installation) or in [this very long and impressive thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844579/drupal-commons-site-has-no-style-after-install-missin-js-and-css-files-at-all).

All troubles I run into have to do with file ownership and permissions.

This is my current setup.
Note: This was just a quick hacked installation, quick and dirty. Well my interest is after the general options I have in migrating from Linux to Linux.

```
linux-vi17:/srv/www/htdocs/com624 # ls -l
insgesamt 224
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root www 45285 19. Jan 00:54 CHANGELOG.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root www   925 19. Jan 00:54 COPYRIGHT.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root www   206 19. Jan 00:54 cron.php
drwxrwxrwx  2 root www  4096 19. Jan 00:54 includes
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root www   923 19. Jan 00:54 index.php
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root www  1244 19. Jan 00:54 INSTALL.mysql.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root www  1011 19. Jan 00:54 INSTALL.pgsql.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root www 47073 19. Jan 00:54 install.php
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root www 15572 19. Jan 00:54 INSTALL.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root www 14940 19. Jan 00:54 LICENSE.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root www  1858 19. Jan 00:54 MAINTAINERS.txt
drwxrwxrwx  3 root www  4096 19. Jan 00:54 misc
drwxrwxrwx 35 root www  4096 19. Jan 00:54 modules
drwxrwxrwx  4 root www  4096 19. Jan 00:54 profiles
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root www  1470 19. Jan 00:54 robots.txt
drwxrwxrwx  2 root www  4096 19. Jan 00:54 scripts
drwxrwxrwx  4 root www  4096 19. Jan 00:54 sites
drwxrwxrwx  7 root www  4096 19. Jan 00:54 themes
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root www 26250 19. Jan 00:54 update.php
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root www  4864 19. Jan 00:54 UPGRADE.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root www   294 19. Jan 00:54 xmlrpc.php
linux-vi17:/srv/www/htdocs/com624 #
```

Comment: Your files permissions seems incorrect, have a look at [Securing file permissions and ownership](http://drupal.org/node/244924)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are successfully using rsync for this. It gives you fine-grained control over permission settings, and how they are transferred from one machine to the other one.

A very nice side effect of rsync is that, once properly set up, it gives you a very nice deployment tool. There's even Drush integration available.

Comment: by the way - how easy can i install drush!?